# How to use Open Directory login credentials when offline?

Tags: mac-osx, authentication, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

When using Active Directory, I can log into a machine while on the network using my AD credentials, then later take that machine offline and still be able to log into it.

I'd like to do the same thing using OS X Lion Server and Open Directory.

I haven't tested it yet because I'm not exactly sure where to start.

Is it possible to log into a machine using OS Credentials while offline? If so, is there anything special that needs to be done in order to achieve this?

***background***
Our church has 4 campuses across the city. 2 of those campuses are in rented facilities whereby we don't have direct access to the network (just basic wifi login), and one of those two facilities has a proxy whereby we need to "agree to terms" before getting online.

This adds much headache to our setup, but none the less, we have to deal with it.

I need to be able to deploy Macs at all four campuses, yet be able to manage the machines and user credentials from our mac server located in one of our permanent facilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you have to check the *"Create mobile account at login"* option within the "User Experience" tab of the advanced options of the Directory Utility on each of your client machines. This will enable cached credentials (see page 4 of [this 3rd party documentation](http://www.bu.edu/tech/files/2009/10/AD-OD-10.6-1.pdf) for further reference and some screenshots).

**Disclaimer**: I do not know what I am talking about as I usually do not touch Macs with a stick, not to mention the administration of Apple servers. I am just quoting the docs.